# Is there a modality to modify the elements of a vector/array bit by bit?

Tags: c, memory

I'm setting up a RamBlock "simulation". Using an static array of bools in hexadecimal (10 elements) that need to be modified individually bit by bit.

```
uint8_t boolArray[10] = {0x03, 0xED, 0xE8, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x56, 0x01, 0x02, 0xAB, 0x18};
```

Edit: In the requirements field it's given a prototype function:

```
Std_ReturnType _WriteBoolean(uint8_t ramBlockAddr, uint16_t ramBlockLength, uint16_t byteIndex, uint8_t bitIndex, const uint8_t* value, uint8_t length)
```

AND I'm able to modify the following with it using the parameters: byteIndex, bitIndex, length and value.

The function would look like:

```
returnValue = _WriteBoolean((uint8_t*)&boolArray[0], 10, 0, 3, (uint8_t*) &x, 4);
/*Bits should be written with the value provided by "x"*/
```

I can access elements of boolArray[] via `&boolArray[i]`. Don't know how to modify/update it with a new bool value taken from the function(returnValue).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Use bitwise operations. If you wanna set a bit on, do `boolArray[position] |= (1 << bit - 1)`. If you wanna change a bit to 0, then `boolArray[position] &= ~(1 << bit - 1)`. You could also have an array of unions.

Comment: @VioAriton I thought of that, I will try it, anyways I defined each individual element as "#define BIT1 0x03" ... and initialized the array like "uint8_t boolArray[10] = {BIT1...}. Am I overthinking this? Thank you!

Comment: You can do it however you want, as long as it works. There is no best way. Another approach would be with unions, like [this](https://onlinegdb.com/rJOSlnLT4).

Comment: Forgot, there's a prototype function on the requirement page:`_writeBoolean(uint8_t ramBlockAddr, uint16_t ramBlockLength, uint16_t byteIndex, uint8_t bitIndex, const uint8_t* value, uint8_t length)`. I can also use this to modify the bits in the byte stream selecting where to start, length to be updated, etc as follows: `_writeBoolean((uint8_t*)&boolArray[0], 10, 0, 3, (uint8_t*) &x, 4);`

Comment: And also, let's say I want to store the values from the functions in a variable, then update the array each time a change is made, I can't since the values of the array are defined using macros, right?

Comment: If you want to declare the array inside the function and don't want to lose It's data after the function terminates, use the [static](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/memory-layout-of-c-program/) keyword. The array gets stored in the static zone, and every function call gets its reference

Comment: I want to update each element of the array by using the function `returnValue = _writeBoolean(uint8_t ramBlockAddr, uint16_t ramBlockLength, uint16_t byteIndex, uint8_t bitIndex, const uint8_t* value, uint8_t length)`. I think I need to leave the values of the array hardcoded and remove the defines.

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers by default. You'd have to change `uint8_t ramBlockAddr` to `uint8_t * ramBlockAddr` if you don't dynamically allocate the array inside the function, `uint8_t ** ramBlockAddr` otherwise.

Comment: I suppose its like i did it before: `returnValue = _writeBoolean((uint8_t*)&boolArray[0], 10, 0, 3, (uint8_t*) &x, 4);`.  In order to pass "returnValue" each time, I need to use it as a pointer, correct?

Comment: There are plenty of questions regarding how pointers work on SO. I also highly recommend this [book](https://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Using-Pointers-Techniques-Management/dp/1449344186/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=c+pointers&qid=1558800764&s=books&sr=1-1).

Answer (score 0):

To toggle certain bits on and off, one can use bitwise operations. For example, If we have the value `0x3`, that is 0011 in binary, to turn the third bit on, we could do `value |= (1 << 2)`. We shift the contents of the temporary constant `1` two positions ahead, and we do a `OR` with the value: 0011 | 0100 = 0111.

To turn a bit off, we do the same thing, only that we take the complement of the constant and we do an `AND` with the value: `value &= ~(1 << 2)` => `0111` & `~0100` => `0111` & `1011` => `0011`

A union can be used as well to represent a block of memory:

```
typedef union {

    uint_8 data;

    struct {

      uint8_t cell1;
      uint8_t cell2;
      uint8_t cell3;
      uint8_t cell4;
      uint8_t cell5;
      uint8_t cell6;
      uint8_t cell7;
      uint8_t cell8;

   };

} Block_t
```